# Authentication in WCF Services

Tags: wcf

I'm working in a small project and I need clients to authenticate against a Database in my server,so I implemented a method to do this in my service,my question is if there is a better way of doing this,and what are the advantages of it.For better understanding this is the code of my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool TryAuthenticateUser(string username,string password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom username and password validator. 
You can find info about this on the following link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx